# Generate CSR code on local machine

Tags: tls, openssl, csr

I've tried activating an SSL cert. When it asked for the CSR code, I was thinking about generating this code on local machine because I haven't rented my own VPS yet. The thing is, I'm not sure whether or not the CSR code generated on local server is safe.

Is it required to generate this code on the actual server that's going to host the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to generate the CSR on the machine the certificate is going to be used.

Yet, the private key must be transmitted to the machine it is to be used on at some point, **securely**.

Also, you have to keep the private key **private at all times** especially while it is on multiple machines, which increases the risk of it being compromised; especially if it's your desktop machine you use for daily browsing.

Comment: Do you mean that it's not recommended to generate this code somewhere else other than the actual server?

Comment: You may generate the key pair and/or the CSR wherever you like. You just have to keep tha key pair private at all times. Generation of the pair on a local, completely trusted machine might even be useful in case the hardware randomness of the server you rent is compromised.

Comment: BTW, is it ok to transfer the code via `openssh`?

Comment: Generally a good idea, as long as the used cipher and key exchage suites are secure.

Comment: @Tresdin Adding to SmokeDispenser's comment, you may want to check out [Secure Secure Shell](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html).